symbolic to directory
I have an directory /home/user1/abc, and I want map all path with /home/user1/xyz/abc to /home/user1/abc
before running the ln -s command, /home/user1/abc exist, and /home/user1/xyz, /home/user1/abc is NOT exist.
ls -ld /home/user1/abc
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Dec  2 18:35 /home/user1/abc
ls -ld /home/user1/xyz
ls: cannot access '/home/user1/xyz': No such file or directory
ls -ld /home/user1/xyz/abc
ls: cannot access '/home/user1/xyz/abc': No such file or directory

if /home/user1/xyz/abc is not exist, then when I run
ln -s /home/user1/abc /home/user1/xyz/abc

it returns
No such file or directory

if /home/user1/xyz/abc is exists, then when I run
ln -s /home/user1/abc /home/user1/xyz/abc

it create one more directory
/home/user1/xyz/abc/abc which is not my wants.
what should I do to create an directory symbolic link to map
/home/user1/xyz/abc to /home/user1/abc?

Does /home/user1/xyz exist? Please [edit] your question and clarify which directories exist before running the ln -s command. I suggest to copy & paste the following command with its output: ls -ld /home/user1/abc /home/user1/xyz /home/user1/xyz/abc

yes, I found that /home/user1/xyz must exist, but /home/user1/xyz/abc cannot exist for ln -s /home/user1/abc /home/user1/xyz/abc can do what I want, thanks.

Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this purpose. You should improve the question by adding the information already requested. Then it will be possible to write an answer that is not based on guessing.
